# pandas - calculate average by iterating the filters

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that has the following structure

```
Goals   Team       Day
1     Madrid     monday  
3     Madrid     friday
3     Man U      monday
2     Man u      sunday
etc    etc       etc
```

so I have the data frame with data containing hundreds of teams, days of the week and goals.

what I want to do is create a dataframe with the average in each of the possible combinations between team and day, for example:

```
Team     Day     Average
Madrid   monday    5.6
Madrid   tuesday   6.7
Madrid   tuesday   4.3
Madrid   wednesday 3.5
Madrid   thursday  4.3
Madrid   friday    3.9
Madrid   saturday  9.8
Madrid   sunday    3.4
Man U    monday    4.5
Man U    tuesday   4.2
...       ...      ...
etc       etc      etc
```

How can I do this using pandas and numpy?

I guess I have to use loops but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Team', 'Day'])['Goals'].mean().reset_index()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])

teams = ['Madrid', 'Man U']
days = 'mon tue wed thu fri sat sun'.split()
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Team=np.random.choice(teams, 15),
    Day=np.random.choice(days, 15),
    Goals=np.random.randint(10, size=15)
))
```

---

### `groupby`

```
df.groupby(
    ['Team', 'Day'], 
    as_index=False
).mean().rename(columns=dict(Goals='Average'))

     Team  Day  Average
0  Madrid  fri     8.00
1  Madrid  mon     3.75
2   Man U  mon     7.00
3   Man U  sat     5.00
4   Man U  sun     5.00
5   Man U  thu     7.00
6   Man U  tue     8.00
7   Man U  wed     4.00
```

---

### Explanation

1. I hope `groupby` is self explanatory
2. `as_index=False` tells `groupby` not to put the grouped columns into the index of the result.  It saves me from having to `reset_index`
3. `mean()` takes the average
4. `rename(columns=dict(Goals='Average'))` is just housekeeping to get the desired column name.  I passed a dictionary to the `columns` argument of the `rename` method.

---

### Response to comment

> how do Pandas know which column to take to calculate the average?which happens for example if I have two columns with numerical values and I want to take the average of only one of these columns. How do I tell this to pandas?

You can be more explicit about what column to average by selecting the column after the `groupby`

```
df.groupby(
    ['Team', 'Day'], 
    as_index=False
).Goals.mean().rename(columns=dict(Goals='Average'))
```

Otherwise, Pandas will attempt to average all columns not grouped.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have a question: how do Pandas know which column to take to calculate the average?which happens for example if I have two columns with numerical values and I want to take the average of only one of these columns. How do I tell this to pandas?